# Compare joda.DateTime in filter

Tags: scala, slick, slick-2.0

I'm trying to a Column[DateTime] with a date time in filter, but just can't figure out how to make it work.

```
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.db.slick.Config.driver.simple._
import play.api.db.slick._
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeComparator, DateTimeZone}

  private val dateComparator = DateTimeComparator.getInstance()

  implicit def dateTimeToScalaWrapper(dt: DateTime): DateTimeWrapper = new DateTimeWrapper(dt)

  class DateTimeWrapper(dt: DateTime) extends Ordered[DateTime] with Ordering[DateTime] {
    def compare(that: DateTime): Int = dateComparator.compare(dt, that)
    def compare(a: DateTime, b: DateTime): Int = dateComparator.compare(a, b)
  }

  implicit def jodaType = MappedColumnType.base[DateTime, Timestamp](
  {d => new Timestamp(d.getMillis)} ,
  {d => new DateTime(d.getTime, UTC)}
  )

  def removeTimeSlots(start: DateTime, end: DateTime, reservationId: Long) : Int = DB withTransaction { implicit session =>
    timeSlots.filter(x => x.reservationId == reservationId && x.startTime >= start && x.starTime <= end).delete
  }
```

At the point where I compare x.startTime and start I get the following error:

```
Error:(90, -1) Play 2 Compiler: 
Reservations.scala:90: polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
  found   : [R]scala.slick.lifted.Column[R]
  required: Boolean
```

Any chance I can make those comparisons in my code?

Comment: Help other readers! Cross-link posts between SO and the mailing list.
https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/scalaquery/66b7a3c6-bd74-4269-a990-f46971e2af4b%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer

Comment: will do in future. thanks for the links

Answer (score 1):

Inside `filter`, `map`, etc. in Slick you can only use code which can be translated into SQL; obviously it can't use arbitrary Java/Scala classes like `DateTimeComparator` or `DateTimeWrapper`. Slick [doesn't seem to support datetime comparison currently](https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/627); you may want to watch this issue. See also [Slick: Filtering all records which have a joda DateTime date equal to today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21350399/slick-filtering-all-records-which-have-a-joda-datetime-date-equal-to-today).

Comment: It's surprising, considering the fact that actual column type is Timestamp (via MappedColumnType), and database engines do support operations on it. The lack of dates comparison support basically renders Slick as useless to me at this point

Answer (score 0):

This jodatime mapper is really usefull with Plya! : https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper