# How to compare datepart Month using Nhibernate Criteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, criteria

This is my code:

```
   public IList<VotacaoPlenario> RetornarVotacao(int mesInicio, int anoInicio)
    {
        DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<VotacaoPlenario>();

        if (anoInicio > 0)
        { 
            criteria.Add(Expression.Eq("YEAR(Data)", anoInicio));

        }

        IList<VotacaoPlenario> votacao = criteria.GetExecutableCriteria(Session).List<VotacaoPlenario>();


        return votacao;
    }
}
```

In my table de field Data is Datime i'm need to compare with the variable anoInicio which is int How can i do that?

Comment: This answer might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10932268/507793

Comment: Does not fit in my case

Comment: I need to change the table dates

Answer (score 2):

The solution here could be to use SQL Projection:

```
var monthProjection = Projections
     .SqlProjection(" MONTH(Data) as month "  // the left side of the expression
                   , new[] {"month"}          // alias  
                   , new IType[] {NHibernateUtil.Int32}); // type is int

criteria.Add(Expression.Eq(monthProjection, anoInicio));
```

and the SQL generated would look like this

```
MONTH(Date) = @p1 //where p1 param is anaInicio
```

Comment: Does not either the NHibernate.Transform. in my version is NHibernate.Util

Comment: The *NHibernateUtil* live in a root namespace `NHibernate.NHibernateUtil`. The `Transformer` namespaces is not for Restrictions (as in our case) but for a final SELECT clause to Entity conversion *(mostly for projections)*