# How to extract hour from datetime in criteria?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have to write something like:

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE HOUR(field) = 10
```

Where field is datetime.

I want to ignore the dates - for statistics purpose, I need to extract only events, that occurs between 10:00 and 10:59.

I know, I can:

```
String sql = "HOUR(CREATED_AT) = 10";
criteria.add(Expression.sql(sql));
```

But I'd like to use the hibernate mechanisms, rather than SQL strings.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simple solution** - should work like this:

```
var hourProjection = Projections
     .SqlProjection(" DATEPART(HOUR,field) as hour "  // the left side of the expression
                   , new[] {"hour"}          // alias  
                   , new IType[] {NHibernateUtil.Int32}); // type is int

criteria.Add(Expression.Eq(hourProjection, myValue)); // myValue = 10
```

Check: [How to compare datepart Month using Nhibernate Criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23818419/1679310)

**NHibernate-ish solution** - in case we would like to use that function `HOUR` extensively, we can extend the `Dialect` with its definition:

```
public class CustomMsSql2012Dialect : MsSql2012Dialect
{
    public CustomMsSql2012Dialect()
    {
        RegisterFunction("HOUR", 
            new SQLFunctionTemplate(NHibernateUtil.Class, "DATEPART(HOUR,?1)"));
    }
}
```

And inject that into configuration:

```
<property name="dialect">MyLib.CustomMsSql2012Dialect,MyLib</property>
```

And consume it like this:

```
var hourFunctionProjection = Projections
  .SqlFunction("HOUR", NHibernateUtil.Int32, Projections.Property("Field"));

restrictions.Add(Restrictions.Eq(hourFunctionProjection, 10));
```

Check: [Using SQL CONVERT function through nHibernate Criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22804798/1679310)

Answer (score 1):

This get Hours from datetime

```
select DATEPART(HOUR, field) from tableName
```

Comment: I was so concentrating on the NHibernate stuff *(expecting `HOUR(column)` being a function)*... your SQL-ish way to select HOUR is of course the way on DB side...